# clang in neovim giving pp_file_not_found error for c++/pytorch basic example

Tags: c++, cmake, pytorch, clang, libtorch

I'm following this very basic c++/pytorch example:

[pytorch_installing](https://pytorch.org/cppdocs/installing.html#support)

And I can walk through this example with no errors. However, when creating the example-app.cpp file (or editing it at any point in time) with neovim, clang throws an error `'torch/torch.h' file not found [clang: pp_file_not_found]`. My CMakeLists.txt file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
include_directories(SYSTEM /home/username/Downloads/libtorch/)
set(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH "/home/username/Downloads/libtorch/share/cmake/Torch")
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

This isn't a big issue for me with this small of a project. But I will be working on a larger project with libtorch and would like clang to recognize <torch/torch.h>. There were a couple similar Stackoverflow questions, but no answers.

Update:

I believe this is happening because clang is not seeing `torch/torch.h` because it is not part of the include paths. I printed the include paths for clang and it was not list. So I tried adding the include paths of libtorch to /usr/include/ but then it has issues seeing other header files referenced by header files I added. So I added the `libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/` directory to `/usr/include` so that it can read `#include <torch/torch.h`. But then other header files are referenced in those header files with specified directory paths outside of the `libtorch/include/torch/csrc/api/include/torch/` path.

For example, `libtorch/include/torch/csrc/` contains `WindowsTorchApiMacro.h`. There are other paths within the `libtorch` directory that contain more header files. I tried to add all header files to `\usr\include` but still received an error. I'm sure the package as a whole needs to be used. The original cmake file looks like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(example-app)

find_package(Torch REQUIRED)
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} ${TORCH_CXX_FLAGS}")

add_executable(example-app example-app.cpp)
target_link_libraries(example-app "${TORCH_LIBRARIES}")
set_property(TARGET example-app PROPERTY CXX_STANDARD 14)
```

So cmake is able to find and reference all of those header files properly, and I know you can compile it at the command line with clang, but how can clang within neovim (during editing) see this package without error? I thought about using a package manager like vcpkg, but they do not have libtorch available, unfortunately. I can include output from a verbose and successful cmake run if needed.

Comment: Just to be sure I understand : if you cmake - make your project, the setup works and the compilation succeeds, but on the other hand the clang compiler inside neovim (for autocompletion I assume) fails to find the headers and thus your automcompletion is broken. Is that about right ?

Comment: @trialNerror, yes. It won't recognize <torch/torch.h> and so every reference to torch becomes an error within neovim, and if I put `#inlcude <torch/torch.h>` at the top of the file, subsequent `#include ,...`'s aren't read properly and become errors as well. I can take a screenshot if that will help.

Comment: OKay then, does your autompletion plugin support compilation databases (for example, YouCompleteMe does) ? That would be the most straightforward way to solve this. CMake can be set to produce the compilation database that you then provide to your autocompleter. This file explicits all required flags and paths for all compilation units in your project, and thus your neovim clang cannot really make mistakes or get lost in your filesystem anymore

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. So I needed to enable a file generation with my CMake build by adding `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1` to my build to generate a `compile_commands.json` file in the build directory. I then just moved that file from the build directory to the root of my project and it fixed the issue. Thanks! Feel free to add that to an answer and I'll give the bounty.

Comment: @trialNerror, one side question. Where should I store libtorch on Ubuntu? I currently just have it in my Downloads folder. Is there a standard location for libtorch, or any other external package, for that matter?

Comment: Not really, as far as I know. I for example just have a `libs` folder in my home in which I save all third party libraries (like torch, sfml, you name it...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the compilation succeeds with cmake-make, it is possible to ask CMake to generate the compilation database (typically a `compile_commands.json` file) with `cmake -DCMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS=1`.

Once the file is available, it can be read by the autocompletion compiler (clang in this case), which prevents the autocompleter from being lost in the filesystem, because all flags and headers are specified for all compilation units.
The compilation database just needs to be put where the autocompletion plugin expects it to be.

Answer (score 0):

You can add at the beginning of your CMakeList.txt

```
set(CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS ON)
```

Or as a cache variable in a CMakePresets.json file if you use one :

```
{
    "version": 1,
    "configurePresets": [
        {
            "name": "debug",
            "displayName": "Debug",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
            "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Debug",
                "CMAKE_EXPORT_COMPILE_COMMANDS": "ON",
                "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT": "-std=c++17 -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -Werror -Weffc++  -Wshadow -O0"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "release",
            "displayName": "Release",
            "binaryDir": "${sourceDir}/build",
            "generator": "Unix Makefiles",
            "cacheVariables": {
                "CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE": "Release",
                "CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_INIT": "-std=c++17 -march=haswell -flto -O3"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```